# SQL Server datatype Int

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I'm trying to insert values in an `int` column (`Filenum`)

```
INSERT INTO Tbl (Filenum, Fname, Sname, Tname, Lname, DOB, NatID, SexID, AdrsCtryID, AdrsStateID, AdrLin1, FileStatID, MarStatID, OcupID, Email, SSnum, Passnum, TelMob, TelLnd, TelWrk, TelWrkExt, TelInt, strno, Direction, AptNo, locality, adminLvl, postalcode, Contr, UsrID, LogID)
VALUES (@FileNum, @Fname, @Sname, @Tname, @Lname, @DOB, @NatID, @SexID, @AdrsCtryID, @AdrsStateID, @AdrLin1, @FileStatID, @MarStatID, @OcupID, @email, @SSnum, @Passnum, @TelMob, @TelLnd, @TelWrk, @TelWrkExt, @TelInt, @strno, @Direction, @AptNo, @locality, @adminLvl, @postalcode, @Contr, @UsrID, @LogID)
```

Values like (777777777) with 9 digits are allowed whereas 10 digit values give me this error

> The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid .net framework data type int32

Any idea why?

Comment: 32 bit signed integers have a max value of 2,147,483,648

Comment: Please tell me that you are not storing SSN in plain text.

Comment: actually I encrypt it and save it, yes, could you please correct me here if I m compromising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

max size for 4 byte signed integer: 2147483648

Try using a `bigint` in sql server, and a 64bit signed int `long` in .net.

Reference:

- [Integral Types Table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table)
- [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)

Comment: thanks for the promot help... I m using this field as a primary key,,, based on my humble knowledge, int are the best to be used as primary key in relational dbs, am i correct?

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar It is a good _clustering_ key (primary key is clustered by default in sql server), yes. `bigint` will be fine too.  [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again! - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)

Comment: Thank you all so much, I really appreciate any input on how to save SSN efficiently